# Linked list basic advice for beginner is needed

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Teacher said write program with four functions (print size or add, remove and print node). In line 17 error comes (Cannot convert int* into node). I can't find other way to represent this line so please help. Since it's my first experience with linked list, you can expect tons of error.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{                // Declaring the node (2 way)
    int n;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
int *header;                //Declaring header and size counter
int size;

int *finder(int number)     //Function that return address of selected node       
{
    int *adr;
    int c;
    struct node *temp;
    temp=header;
    c=0;
    while(c==number)
    {
         temp=temp->next;
         c=c+1;
    }
return adr;
}

void insert(int data,int number)    //insert new node after specified node
{
    int *adr;
    adr=finder(number);
    struct node *current;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *temp;

    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current=adr;
    previous=current->prev;

    temp->n=data;
    temp->next=current;
    temp->prev=current->prev;

    previous->next=temp;
    current->prev=temp;

    size=size+1;
}

void remove(int number)             //remove node after selected one
{
    int *adr;
    adr=finder(number);
    struct node *current;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *neeext;
    current=adr;
    previous= current->prev;
    neeext= current->next;

    previous->next= neeext;
    neeext->prev= previous;
}

void print(int number)          //print data of node
{
    int *adr;
    adr=finder(number);
    struct node *current;
    printf("%d",current->n);
}

int main()                          //main function
{
    int i,j,d;
    size=0;
    for(i=1;i<5;i=i+0)
    {
        if(i==1)
        {
            printf("%d",size);  
        }
        scanf("%d",&j);
        if(i==2)
        {
            scanf("%d",&d);
            insert(d,j);
            printf("inserted");
        }
        if(i==3)
        {
            remove(j);
            printf("removed");
        }
        if(i==4)
        {
            print(j);
        }
        if(i==5)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        scanf("%d",&i);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the incorrect type for `header`, look at `finder` closely. Given any `number` that is *non-zero*, how long do you think `while(c==number)` is going to loop when you just set `c = 0;` on the previous line? For that matter, you `return adr;` at the bottom of the function but never bother to set it to anything determinate *anywhere*.

Comment: It might be better to get a single ('forward') linked list correct before dealing with a 2-way linked list. Also, some kind of `dump` function that prints each node, its content, and the pointer values might help you debug linked list operations.

Comment: have a look at http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Comment: Strongly suggest: when compiling, always enable all warnings.  For gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  then fix those warnings, after all, the compiler knows the C language much better than us humans.  For the posted code,  the compiler will raise several messages include such items as: /usr/include/stdiio.h:178:12: note: previous declaration of 'remove' was here   I.E. `remove()` is a system function and it is a no-no to write your own version of system functions.   Suggest changing the name of your function, perhaps to `deleteNextNode()`

Comment: suggest, after fixing all the problems noted by the compiler, to use a debugger, like gdb, to step through the code to see what is actually being done.

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is not portable and the code is not using any of its' features,  suggest commenting out or (better) removing that statement from the code'

Comment: this comment: `//Declaring header and size counter` is only repeating the code.   We can read the code.  What is actually needed for comments is the `why` `current conditions` and/or explanation of algorithm used.

Comment: the `finder()` function actually returns a pointer to a `struct node`, not an `int`.  The loop in the `finder()` function will walk right past the end of the linked list and be trying to step through random memory.  This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event. Suggest, in the while statement to also be checking for a NULL in the `next` field  And when the desired node is not found, return a NULL.  As it is , the value in 'adr' is what ever trash was on the stack where the declaration of adr is located

Comment: when calling the system function: `malloc()`, do not cast the returned value.  A cast is not necessary, clutters the code, and can be a maintenance nightmare.   Immediately after calling `malloc()`, check (!=NULL) the returned value to  assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `insert()` returns a 'void'.  How is the caller of that function expected to know if the insert operation was successful?   In general, never assume anything when writing code.  I.E. always check for errors

Comment: in the function: `insert()`, the values of the `current` pointer and the `previous` pointer, point to trash.  It would be a good idea to start with the `header` variable pointer, find where you want to insert the new node, set all the pointers appropriately, then insert the new node.

Comment: the `delete()` function forgets to pass the pointer to the free'd node to the `free()` function, This oversight results in a memory leak

Comment: the `main()` function logic would be better implemented as some straight line code.  the `j` variable is not set to any specific value, so contains what every trash was in the stack at the location where the `j` variable is defined.  Strongly suggest re-thinking the logic AND determine exactly what you want to accomplish (write it down as a series of steps) before even trying to debug the current code.  The 'data' being passed to the `insert()` function is what ever trash was at the stack where the 'd' variable was defined, and might not even be a valid integer

Comment: the `main()` function fails to pass all the malloc'd memory areas (the nodes in the linked list) to `free()` resulting in memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your `header` variable as `struct node *header;`, not as `int*`

Comment: while this does answer the question, there are many many other things wrong with the code.